# Why is it incorrect for the main() method using a class Clock to have the second statement below?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Clock c = new Clock();
  c.m = c.m + 1;
  //where m is a private instance variable in an another class.`
}
```

Why is it incorrect for the main() method using a class Clock to have the second statement below? Please help?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: you can do one thing generate setter getter for m instance variable on clock class and from main method  call using c.getm(); that will give the data of m . since private variable you can not access out side of the class that's why use setter getter concept

Comment: What did the compiler tell you when you tried to compile this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access private members outside of the class
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a private instance outside a class.It is local to the class it is declared in.If you want to do so, make it public, then you can access it using the class object.